# Python dictionary word search/creator?

Tags: python, search, cpu-word

I have .txt files containing a dictionary full of words; now I want to input several letters and find each word in the dictionary that is made up of those letters.

i.g.  I type in the letters "D, D, A" and the program searches through the text file and returns all words that can be made using those letters, in this case it should return words such as "A, AD, ADD, DAD".

Can anyone please show me how this can be done.

Thanks A

Comment: I doubt anyone will craft a solution for you from scratch. Show us what you have tried, tell us what isn't working, and you will get a much better response.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
In [242]: mylist = ['D', 'D', 'A']

In [243]: l = []

In [244]: for i in range(1, len(mylist)+1):
   .....:     for x in list(itertools.permutations(mylist, i)):
   .....:         l.append(''.join(x))
   .....:

In [245]: set(l)
Out[245]: set(['A', 'DAD', 'D', 'DD', 'DA', 'ADD', 'DDA', 'AD'])
```

then for each item in the set, search in the text file if it s valid word